# How can I create a GMT file from a tab delimited file?

Tags: awk

I have a file like this:

File 1:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | GO:0001 | description1 |
| Gene3 | GO:0002 | description2 |
| Gene2 | GO:0003 | description3 |
| Gene5 | GO:0002 | description2 |
| Gene4 | GO:0003 | description3 |

and I would like to transform it into this:

File 2:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GO:0001 | description1 | Gene1 |  |
| GO:0002 | description2 | Gene3 | Gene5 |
| GO:0003 | description3 | Gene2 | Gene4 |

Basically, I have a tab delimited file 1 and I want to transform it into a GMT file like file 2, but I don't know how.

I found this command line:

```sh
sort -k2,2 input.txt | awk '{
    if ($2 != prev) {
        printf "%s%s\tNA\t%s", (NR == 1 ? "" : "\n"), $2, $1
        prev = $2
        next
    } else {
        printf " %s", $1
    }
}

END {
    printf ("\n")
}' > output.txt
```

here: https://www.biostars.org/p/121746/

but I don't know how to adapt it to my File 1.
If someone can help me I will appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to replace the graphical tables with raw text so we have something we can copy/paste to test with. Never post links, or images or anything other than simply a [mcve] with concise, testable, textual sample input and expected output. Make sure your sample input, output, and code is formatted correctly, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to do that and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of how to ask a good question as well as [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton looks like markdown tables are used to show the content. But all the mentioned points are valid :)

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I know, I'm telling the OP not to do that because then we don't know what the real data files look like (Are the fields quoted? Which char really separates them? Can the fields contain white space? etc.) and we can't copy/paste them to test with so we're left guessing at the requirements and unable to test a potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the header, this script should give the desired output.

```sh
awk '{a[$2"\t"$3]=a[$2"\t"$3]"\t"$1} END{for (key in a){print key"\t"a[key]}}' file
```

If your desired output should contain `NA`, it seems like there is no logic, but blindly adding the NA column. Below snippet should work.

```sh
awk '{a[$2"\t"$3]=a[$2"\t"$3]"\t"$1} END{for (key in a){print key"\tNA\t"a[key]}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what the "NA" is determined there. I'd entirely skip the sorting step. Try :

```
gawk -b -e '{ inpL[($2""$3)][NR] = $1 
  
} END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";

     for(goX in inpL) { 
        printf("%30s", goX);

        for(scigtRowNum in inpL[goX]) { 

            printf(" %s",inpL[goX][scigtRowNum])
        }; 

     printf(ORS) } }'
```

Comment: `($2""$3)` = `$2$3`. You can't create a unique string by just concatenating 2 strings. Imagine $2 is `a` and $3 is `bc`, the string resulting from `$2$3` (or `($2""$3)`) would be `abc`. Now imagine $2 is `ab` and $3 is `c`. Hopefully you see the problem. You need to use `$2,$3` (for array indices) or `$2 FS $3` or similar to create a unique string from the concatenation of 2 strings that can't contain  the separator char/string you put between them.

Comment: If you skip the sorting step then you have to read the whole file into memory and do a 2-pass approach within awk. sorting the input first is the most efficient approach in terms of both memory and speed of execution.

Comment: is it really "2-pass" considering one of the requirements was to re-shape the data and be grouped by GO: number (and not a straight-up row/col transpose either).

Comment: is it really "2-pass" considering one of the requirements was to re-shape the data and be grouped by GO: number (and not a straight-up row/col transpose either). unless the file is beyond 100MB zone, i'm not sure if gawk in byte-mode is noticeably slower, if at all. With mawk2, on my 2018 laptop, it can load a full 987MB text file all in one shot, and split it out into 107.6 million fields (NF = 107,639,767) in 12.6 seconds. It took 1.90 secs to load in a 153MB file and flat split into 24.3 million fields (NF = 24,351,796). Speed isn't much concern for AWK

Comment: I removed the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) tag. It didn’t seem relevant here.

Comment: Yes, it's really 2-pass. Once to read the data into memory and then again to loop on that data for output. When you talk about MB and NF instead of NR and NF and millions of fields it sounds like you did your timing on an input file that only contains 1 long line. An input file with millions of lines and 4 or 5 fields per line would be a more realistic test case than 1 line with millions of fields. Awk and a newer mawk will only do field splitting up til the max field number mentioned in your script so having 3 fields or 10 million fields is irrelevant if your script only mentions up to $3.

Comment: it's not 1 long line. The 987MB file has these specs :  5,979,986 lines       968,603,891 utf8 (inc 33,613,159 multi-byte Unicode, mostly Korean hangul) 987.825 MB, and NF = 19 each row (18 fields and 1 trailing "=") . I use "=" equal sign as my standard per-row delimiter to avoid any quotation needs, console terminal safe, hardly interfere with any regex (i don't really use equiv-classes or perl $=), and least likely to appear inside a song or artist (solo or group) name. i set FS = "[=\n]+" for this speed demo.

Comment: for another file, here's the term output from macos : time pv < "${m3t}" | mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = "[=\n]+"; RS = "^$"} END { print NF }'
1.85GiB 0:00:01 [1.12GiB/s] [=========================================================================>] 100%            
159239381

real 0m20.558s
user 0m11.083s
sys 0m9.279s. 12.5 million rows, 13+1 fields each, and mawk2 splits it out to 159 million fields in less than 21 seconds.

Comment: that same file using split( ) into array instead of fields : time mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = RS = "^$"} END { print split($0, arr0, /[=\n]+/) }' "${m3t}"
159239381
real 0m19.416s. 
time gawk -b -e 'BEGIN { FS = RS = "^$"} END { print split($0, arr0, /[=\n]+/) }' "${m3t}"
159239381 real 1m4.931s. mawk2-beta (1.9.9.6) is 3.34x faster than gawk : GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) in this one task. Not bad for loading a 1.85GB file all in one shot.

Comment: i've been advocating for a while - for anyone serious about big data analytics, if they want fancy algorithms and stat distributions, use python3. if they really want speed and don't wanna deal with compiling C/C++ (and all the headaches about pointers and garbage collection), AWK is the best thing possible. yes mawk2 is still single-threaded, but with the help of xargs or gnu parallel, it's very competitive against the most modern langs for anything that can't be offloaded to GPU.